# convergence not achieved after 80 iterations

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, numerical-convergence

I am trying to run a scf calculations to obtain the band structure. However,  in the output file, it is show that the convergence is not achieved after 80 iterations.

```
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  etot_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-03
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'aiida'
  pseudo_dir = './'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
/
&SYSTEM
  degauss =   1.4699723600d-02
  ecutrho =   480
  ecutwfc =   80
  ibrav = 8
  celldm(1) = 10.448522166
  celldm(2) = 1.014828084
  celldm(3) = 1.432182555
  nat = 20
  nosym = .false.
  nspin = 2
  ntyp = 3
  !occupations = 'fixed'
  nbnd = 104
  !smearing = 'fermi-dirac'
  tot_magnetization =   0

/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   1.D-6
  electron_maxstep = 120
  mixing_beta =   5.0000000000d-01
/
...
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: You need to show the full input file and kindly upload the output file so that the convergence trend can be seen. Also, please respond to the comments in your other questions.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin Kindly tell me how to upload file here,I shall be uploading input and output files as well.Regards.